# Send POST multipart/form-data request using restbed C++

Tags: c++, rest, multipartform-data, restbed

I am working on a C++ rest client using **restbed** lib that will send a base64 encoded image using a POST request.
The code I wrote so far is :

```
auto request = make_shared< Request >(Uri("http://127.0.0.1:8080/ProcessImage"));
request->set_header("Accept", "*/*");
request->set_header("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW");
request->set_header("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
request->set_method("POST");
string test = "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW"
    "Content-Disposition:form-data;name=\"image\""
    ""
    "testMessage"
    "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--";
request->set_body(imgContent);
auto response = Http::sync(request)
```

I am not sure how I should set the request body. I tried with simple image="blabla" and also with this long version message I took from postman.
But in every case I received a "error 400 Bad request" answer.

Update:
Tested also with this version of code but with no success:

```
auto request = make_shared< Request >(Uri("http://127.0.0.1:8080/ProcessImage"));
    request->set_header("Accept", "*/*");
    request->set_header("Host","127.0.0.1:8080");
    request->set_method("POST");
    request->set_header("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW");
    request->set_header("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    string imgContent = "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\n"
        "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"\r\n"
        "\r\n"
        "test\r\n"
        "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--\r\n";
    request->set_body(imgContent
    auto response = Http::sync(request);
```

The response I get from the server:

```
    *** Response ***
Status Code:    400
Status Message: BAD REQUEST
HTTP Version:   1.0
HTTP Protocol:  HTTP
Header 'Content-Length' > '192'
Header 'Content-Type' > 'text/html'
Header 'Date' > 'Sun, 04 Feb 2018 21:09:45 GMT'
Header 'Server' > 'Werkzeug/0.14.1 Python/3.5.4'
Body:<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.</p>
²²²²∩x...
```

Also on the server side  (which is using python flask) I added:
encoded_img = request.form.get('image') and printed the string. The print result was: "None"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your body content is missing explicit line break characters at the end of each line. C++ does not insert them automatically for you.

Also, if you are going to send base64 data, you should include a `Content-Transfer-Encoding` header, too.

Try this:

```
string imgContent = "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\n"
    "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"\r\n"
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n"     
    "\r\n"
    "<base64 image data here>\r\n"
    "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--\r\n";
request->set_body(imgContent);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried with your version but unfortunately I still got an error 400. Now the message looks identical with the one from postman. Maybe I'm missing a header or something or I'm adding one wrongly. I updated the post with the version of code I used.

Comment: @Alex the headers and content look fine. Can you show the *raw* request data that is actually being transmitted to the server? Maybe `Http::sync` is adding something that is wrong. Is there anything being logged on the server side to explain what it thinks is bad about the request? Is there any body content in the 400 response explaining the problem?

Comment: This is the reposnse I get: *** Response ***
Status Code:    400
Status Message: BAD REQUEST
HTTP Version:   1.0
HTTP Protocol:  HTTP
Header 'Content-Length' > '192'
Header 'Content-Type' > 'text/html'
Header 'Date' > 'Sun, 04 Feb 2018 21:09:45 GMT'
Header 'Server' > 'Werkzeug/0.14.1 Python/3.5.4'
Body:<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.</p>
²²²²∩x...

Comment: Also on the server side (which is using python flask) I added: encoded_img = request.form.get('image') and printed the string. The print result was: "None"

I will need to see how I can check the raw request because indeed maybe Http::sync adds something wrong to the request.

Comment: In the end I managed to print the request and it looks identical with the one fomr postman. But the one from postmand works and the on I wrote doens't. I don't know what the problem is but I choose another way to do it.

Comment: @Alex there has to be a difference in the requests, however subtle it is. An *identical* request should be processed the same way regardless of who sent is.

Comment: Yea I know. But from the request text I can't figure out the difference :). Maybe there are other flags either on postman or on restbed which are not printed but I don't know.